# How to return a custom message when a list of tuples is empty?

Tags: python, list, tuples, max

I am trying to write a function that goes through a list of tuples and return the entry with the highest second item in the specific tuple. I have come up with the following code which seems to work well. However when I run this function using an empty list, I get an error. I was wondering how I can improve my code to give a custom message or simply `'None'` if the input list is empty.

```
def max_steps(step_records):
  """DOCSTRING"""

  tuplemax = max(step_records, key = lambda x:x[1])
  return(tuplemax[1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply test if the tuple is "falsy" i.e empty. If it is, return your special value:

```
def max_steps(step_records):
    if not step_records:
        return None
    tuplemax = max(step_records, key = lambda x:x[1])
    return(tuplemax[1])
```

However, rather than returning `None` or some other special value, it would be better to raise a specific exception letting the user know exactly what went wrong:

```
def max_steps(step_records):
    if not step_records:
        raise ValueError('"step_records" may not be empty')
    tuplemax = max(step_records, key = lambda x:x[1])
    return(tuplemax[1])
```